# Logstash remove duplicates in array

Tags: logstash

I've got an array that *can* contain duplicate integers.

Is there a Logstash plugin that would remove duplicates and keep just distinct values?

I know you can write a Ruby script to do it, but I'm curious if there's something out of box already